# script to copy values only from one google sheet to another is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy values only from a specific tab in a google sheet to another google sheet, then delete the tab. Basically, I want to archive some data from one sheet to the next. The sheet needs to be deleted so that the following week, the same sheet # gets copied to the archive sheet.

I've tried a variety of different methods and none of it has worked.

The block of code in particular is this:

```
//Archive the sheet from two weeks ago. This part is still being worked on. Once this is figured out, we can have it automate.
//Something in the final copyTo function is broken.
    function copyInfo() {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PDlQc3bHR4Wa2j72K01HiWCtrto36AXDhVf1d9Ajtpg');
    var sheet = source.getSheets()[15];

    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MGN3UtOgVg2N6V4cWGqCIpFIITZZQV0OtAJNRevM09o');
    var valuesonly = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;
    sheet.copyTo(destination, valuesonly, true);
}
```

However, here is the complete code block so you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
// popup menu on open
function onOpen() {
    Browser.msgBox('Black tabs = data transferred but need more data. Changes: Adhesive vs nonadhesive tabs were removed and in their place, Solvent and Latex tabs were created to follow the flow of the inventory template sheet.  IMPORTANT: Please notify Carrie if you add lines to the sheets so she can make sure data is correctly allocated on the weekly inventory template. Thank you!', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}

//Custom menu located on the top menu bar called "Custom Menu"
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu').addItem('Copy Weekly Inventory', 'copyTo').addSeparator().addItem('Archive', 'copyInfo').addToUi();
}

//Copy the 3rd sheet from the left to a new sheet, and name that sheet with today's date. 
//Copy the previous week's unopened data to new sheet.
function copyTo(spreadsheet) {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PDlQc3bHR4Wa2j72K01HiWCtrto36AXDhVf1d9Ajtpg');
    var sheet = source.getSheets()[2];
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PDlQc3bHR4Wa2j72K01HiWCtrto36AXDhVf1d9Ajtpg');

    sheet.copyTo(destination);

    var thisDate = new Date();
    Logger.log(thisDate);
    var month = new Array();
    month[0] = "Jan";
    month[1] = "Feb";
    month[2] = "Mar";
    month[3] = "Apr";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "Jun";
    month[6] = "Jul";
    month[7] = "Aug";
    month[8] = "Sep";
    month[9] = "Oct";
    month[10] = "Nov";
    month[11] = "Dec";
    var mo = month[thisDate.getMonth()];
    Logger.log(mo);

    var day = thisDate.getDate();
    Logger.log(day);

    var thisDatePart = mo + ' ' + day;
    Logger.log(thisDatePart);

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var first = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Copy of WeeklyInventoryTemplate"));
    var second = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of WeeklyInventoryTemplate");
    second.setName(thisDatePart);

    var copyInfo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[16];
    var source = copyInfo.getRange(6, 2, 315, 1)
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(thisDatePart).getRange(6, 5, 315, 1)
    source.copyTo(destination);
}

//Archive the sheet from two weeks ago. This part is still being worked on. Once this is figured out, we can have it automate.
//Something in the final copyTo function is broken.
function copyInfo() {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PDlQc3bHR4Wa2j72K01HiWCtrto36AXDhVf1d9Ajtpg');
    var sheet = source.getSheets()[15];

    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MGN3UtOgVg2N6V4cWGqCIpFIITZZQV0OtAJNRevM09o');
    var valuesonly = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;
    sheet.copyTo(destination, valuesonly, true);
}
```

Comment: Provide [mcve] Doesn't work is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what your functions boil down to:

```
function copyTo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PDlQc3bHR4Wa2j72K01HiWCtrto36AXDhVf1d9Ajtpg');//same id
  var sheet1 = source1.getSheets()[2];
  var dest1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PDlQc3bHR4Wa2j72K01HiWCtrto36AXDhVf1d9Ajtpg');//same id
  sheet1.copyTo(dest1);//So this is a copy of third sheet from left

  var thisDatePart =Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM dd")
  var second = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of WeeklyInventoryTemplate");
  second.setName(thisDatePart);   
  var source2 = ss.getSheets()[16].getRange(6,2,315,1);
  var dest2 = ss.getSheetByName(thisDatePart).getRange(6,5,315,1)
  source2.copyTo(dest2);//copy data from 17th sheet from left to sheet named month day i.e. theDatePart
}

function copyInfo() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PDlQc3bHR4Wa2j72K01HiWCtrto36AXDhVf1d9Ajtpg');//different ids
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[15];//16th sheet from left
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MGN3UtOgVg2N6V4cWGqCIpFIITZZQV0OtAJNRevM09o');//different ids
  var valuesonly = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;
  sheet.copyTo(destination,valuesonly,true);//This copies the 16th sheet from left to another spreadsheet. 
}
```

You had two lines here:

```
  var first = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Copy of WeeklyInventoryTemplate"));
  var second = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of WeeklyInventoryTemplate");
```

But you weren't doing anything with 'first' so I'm wondering are you trying to get a copy of a template?

You also had a function parameter named 'spreadsheet' but you never used it in the body of the function.

I think it's kind of dangerous to use references like this: `source.getSheets()[15];` because I believe they can be changed by users moving the tabs around.

I didn't see where you deleted a tab/sheet.